# How to ensure all Postgres queries have WHERE clause?

Tags: postgresql

I am building a multi tenant system in which many clients data will be in the same database.

I am paranoid about some developer forgetting to put the appropriate "WHERE clientid = " onto every query.

Is there a way to, at the database level, ensure that every query has the correct WHERE = clause, thereby ensuring that no query will ever be executed without also specifying which client the query is for?

I was wondering if maybe the query rewrite rules could do this but it's not clear to me if they can do so.

thanks

Comment: `select * from very_big_table WHERE 1=1;` voila! there is your where-clause ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deny permissions on the table `t` for all users. Then give them permission on a function `f` that returns the table and accepts the parameter client_id:

```
create or replace function f(_client_id integer)
returns setof t as
$$
    select *
    from t
    where client_id = _client_id
$$ language sql
;

select * from f(1);
 client_id | v 
-----------+---
         1 | 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to create a `VIEW` for:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t
WHERE t.client_id = current_setting('session_vars.client_id');
```

And use `SET session_vars.client_id = 1234` at the start of the session.

Deny acces to the tables, and leave only permissins for views.

You may need to create rewrite rules for `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `INSERT` for the views (it depends on your PostgreSQL version).

Performance penalty will be small (if any) because PostgreSQL will rewrite the queries before execution.